# Checking a proof involving flows

Tags: differential-geometry

I am going through the proof of theorem 2.12 of the book *Lectures on the geometry of Poisson manifolds* by I. Vaisman. It's just a bit of differential geometry, but as I don't use these methods very often I would like to check if what I am doing is correct.

The setting is the following: we have a Poisson manifold $(M,\{,\})$. To each $f\in C^\infty(M)$ we associate the Hamiltonian vector field $X_f$ corresponding (as a derivation) to $\{f,\bullet\}$. We know that $[X_f,X_g] = X_{\{f,g\}}$ and that the flow $\phi_f^t$ of $X_f$ is a Poisson automorphism. Consider the Lie algebra $\chi=\{\mathrm{Hamiltonian\ vector\ fields}\}$. I want to show that for any $X_f\in\chi$ and $t$ such that the flow exists we have
$$(\phi_f^t)_*\chi = \chi.$$
So let $X_g\in\chi$ and $h\in C^\infty(M)$. Then we have
$$\begin{align}
[(\phi_f^t)_*X_g](h) = & X_g(h\circ\phi_f^t)\\
= & \{g,h\circ\phi_f^t\}\\
= & \{g\circ\phi_f^{-t},h\}\circ\phi_f^t\\
= & [X_{g\circ\phi_f^{-t}}(h)]\circ\phi_f^t\\
= & (X_{g\circ\phi_f^{-t}}\circ\phi_f^t)(h),
\end{align}$$
and we are done. Is this correct?

Also, I tried to do it in the following way: we have
$$(\phi_f^t)_*X_g = \left.\frac{d}{ds}\right|_{s=0}\phi_f^t\circ\phi_g^s.$$
Now from the Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff formula, I would expect this to give me (by exchanging the flows on the left-hand side) something like
$$(\phi_f^t)_*X_g = X_g(\phi_f^t) + \frac{1}{2}X_{\{f,g\}}(\phi_f^t).$$
Is there a way to make this work?